# Why is my xmlhtpp request is returning an empty array?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm requesting data from my `data.php` file with the following request:

```
xmlhttp.send('request=getchartdata&'+'chart='+chart+'&'+'key='+key);
```

Here's the content of `data.php`:

```
if ($_POST["request"] == "getchartdata") {

    /*Removing dash from key*/
    $key = str_replace("-", "", $_POST["key"]);

    if ($_POST["chart"] == "associationEvolutionSubventions") {
        $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT grantYear, grantAmount FROM granttoassociation WHERE HEX(grantReceiver) = ? ");
        /*grantReceiver is in binary*/
    }

    $result->execute(["{$key}"]);
    while($rs = $result->fetch()) {
        if ($outp != "") {
            array_push($outp,$rs); 
        }
    }
}

$outp = json_encode($outp);
echo($outp);
```

However, I'm getting an empty array in `xmlhttp.responseText`.

The connexion to the MySQL Database isn't the issue (another xmlhtpp request is returning data correctly). There's a few point where I'm unsure about my code though:

- `$result->execute(["{$key}"]);` Is the syntax correct here?
- `HEX(grantReceiver)` Is it correct to do this, given grantReceiver is in binary?
- `$key = str_replace("-", "", $_POST["key"]);` Is it the correct syntax for removing dash?

**Edit: here's the full AJAX code as requested.**

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "wp-content/plugins/mygaloochart/data.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send('request=getchartdata&'+'chart='+chart+'&'+'key='+key);
```

Comment: post your full ajax code

Comment: `xmlhttp.send('request=getchartdata&'+'chart='+chart+'&'+'key='+key);` is not enough to understand where is the problem.

Comment: you print_r your full `post` variable in `data.php` and see what value do you have in `post` variable

Comment: Don't treat your system as a giant black box. You can extract information for almost every step. In your case, it looks like you're just composing a SQL query that doesn't return any row. And, oh, `"{$key}"` is just an extremelly convoluted alternative to `$key`.

Comment: It looks like your curly braces aren't closed.

Comment: They are, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your code. You should listen to onreadystate after Opening the request and setting request headers(The following is your revised code):

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "wp-content/plugins/mygaloochart/data.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
};
xmlhttp.send('request=getchartdata&'+'chart='+chart+'&'+'key='+key);
```

Comment: As pointed in the comment above, the issue is coming from the SQL request. But thanks, i'll rearrange my code as you suggest.